# JSONObject(doc.text()) not working in a particular case

Tags: html, json, web-scraping, jsoup

I'm trying to parse HTML output by converting it into JSON object as below

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(doc.text());
```

But it's working in first case and other case throwing error

`as Method threw 'org.json.JSONException' exception. A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]`

I'm using `Jsoup.connect` to url in both case to fetch required document

[Working case doc](https://gist.github.com/vikramvi/fb883bb199e1990582b511edb8ccfa49)

[Non working case doc](https://gist.github.com/vikramvi/3c2fdfec28902ea383218dfbe87b00bd)

For now I need to do working as

```
doc.selectFirst("#INCOME-STATEMENT > div:nth-of-type(2) > table > tbody > tr:nth-of-type(13)").text()
```

instead of JSON object parsing

```
json.getJSONArray("valuation_overview_table_data").getJSONObject(0).get("thisFund")
```

in the 1st working case.

Please clarify how to fix 2nd case or is there a better working around ?